# Configuring urlManager Rules in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, configuration, yii2, yii-url-manager

I'm new to using Yii2 and have been using the urlManager, I have the following code, it works fine however I think that this should be shorter.  I have a couple rules as follows :-

```
    'rules' => [        
        'gifts/<subjectone:[\s\S]+>/<subjecttwo:[\s\S]+>' => 'gifts/index',
            'gifts/<subjectone:[\s\S]+>/<subjecttwo:[\s\S]+>/' => 'gifts/index',
            'gifts/<subjectone:[\s\S]+>' => 'gifts/index',
            'gifts/<subjectone:[\s\S]+>/' => 'gifts/index',
     ];
```

As you can see I've added the 4 rules all to go to the same page to handle different situations.

I've had to add the same Url's twice, once with the `/` and one without to stop 404's. Please advise of a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `+|(\/?)` at trailing of your rule. Take a look:

```
 'gifts/<subjectone:[\s\S]+>+|(\/?)' => 'gifts/index',
```

So there is no need to write your rules twice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer